# Bug rewarding extra Marshal badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

There seems to be a bug rewarding extra Marshal badges. I flagged two things yesterday; both were marked as helpful. Now, my account is showing two new Marshal badges.

As cool as it is to get a gold badge whenever I flag a post, this should probably be fixed.

(The 7 at the top of this screenshot should be a 5. The two new notifications are bogus.)
[image: the achievements drop-panel showing two extra badges, the badge at the top of the screen also shows an inaccurately high number]

Comment: Either way, it's nice to see some honesty.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

This was already fixed in the sense that you don't actually have any extra badges anymore. The inbox notifications persist, however. This bug was network-wide, affecting the Marshal and Excavator badges. For details, see [Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280023)